# bower dependencies to CONCAT to a project

Tags: gruntjs, bower, bower-install

I have a project and the current bower dependencies are a good fit for me.
is there a way to concat them to the project without each time call bower install?

Answer (score 0):

To concat assets you should look at [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat). This will allow you to concatenate all your files.

In terms of the bower install you shouldn't have to run that each time, only when there is a fresh install of the project and the dependencies need to be added.
Bower install will install the dependencies needed and bower update will update dependencies based on what is specified in the bower.json.